# python, perl socket blocking difference when reading data from it?

Tags: python, sockets

In Perl, I can do

```
socket(SERVER, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
bind(SERVER, $my_addr);
listen(SERVER, SOMAXCONN);
$client_address = accept(CLIENT, SERVER);
$line = <CLIENT>;  # Read until newline or EOF
print $line
```

when access it via browser `$line = <CLIENT>` will return and print without blocking. if I'm trying to the same in python with following

```
from socket import *
host = ""
port = 9000
address = (host, port)
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(SOMAXCONN)
client, addr = server.accept()
client_fd = client.makefile()
data = client_fd.readlines()
print data
```

`client_fd.readlines()` is blocking unless I kill the request in browser. Is there a way to get around this? and why is `<CLIENT>` in perl is not blocking?

Comment: The Perl one *should* be blocking by default. What makes you say it's not?

Comment: @hobbs I'm running it on my computer with a print statement at end and access it via browser it prints out the $line without block. With the python one I hve to killed the request in browser then it will print out

Comment: In Perl, you read one line. In Python, you appear to be reading all the lines.

Comment: @hobbs sorry for not clear on the question.I updated it

Comment: Note that `<CLIENT>` will block until a newline is read or EOF is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (updated) Perl example is reading *one* line from the client; the Python one is reading *all* lines of input from the client, until the socket is closed. And the client doesn't close the socket, because it's hoping to be able to do HTTP keepalive. You should use `readline` instead of `readlines` to read a single line of input. Or, if you're really trying to speak HTTP, you should use a module made for that.